# How To Use Emit in Vue.Js?

Tags: vue.js

In this code, I use Random Axios Data in `getMembers` function.
I wonder if I use the same Data in `getMember`. As far as I know in this case I can use `this.$emit`
but I have no idea how to use this.
I want to get exact data in `getMember(idx)`

```
 methods: {
    getMembers() {
      var vm = this;
      this.axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5')
        .then(res => {
          vm.members = res.data.results;
          console.log(vm.members);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    },
    getMember(idx) {
      this.modal = true;
      var vm = this;
      console.log(idx);
      this.axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/')
        .then(res => {
          vm.member = res.data.results;
          console.log(vm.member);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Seems to be a good start: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events

Comment: Please provide more detail about your question that why you want to emit data if your provided details are for the same component.